# image declaration in external js file in cakephp

Tags: javascript, cakephp

I am declaring an image as

```
  <?php echo $this->Html->image('buttonaft.png', array('alt'=> __('img', true), 'border' => '0'));  ?>
```

inside a javascript file that would be read by default.ctp in cakephp

The code is not able to read the image.

Comment: I may have got confused but is the PHP code inside a JS File?

Comment: this is what i have inside my normal jquery file: $("#restaurantlistitem").css("background-image","url(buttonaft.png)");  and i want to render it through default.ctp   what all would i need to change

Comment: Okay, I've never used CakePHP (so my comments may be rubbish) and I'm sure you can point to a JS file using a PHP file, like so <script src="yourFile.php"> however why not just create an Image Object in the JS? Perhaps this will help... https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLImageElement

Comment: Where is the image supposed to be?

Comment: it is basically a button.. when i click on it.. it changes color.. i am doing that by replacing button.png with buttonaft.png on click using jquery

Comment: Dinesh, you will definitely need to improve your question and add more details. People can't read minds, but they can read text. Things to consider adding: where is everything (code, files), detailed description of what you want to do, what have you tried so far, what are the errors you're getting.

Comment: $("#restaurantlistitem").css("background-image","url(<?php echo $this->Html->url('/app/webroot/images/buttonaft.png', true); ?>");             is my code line..  it is written inside a javascript file... this js file has to be rendered through default.ctp in cakephp.. and that is probably because we cannot declare images as i have done

Answer (score 0):

try to give like this..

but make sure you are giving correct path.

```
echo $html->image('image.png', array('url' => '/' . IMAGES_URL . 'image.png'));
```

you can also do this in 1.2

```
echo $html->link(
    $html->image('img.png'),
    'img.png',
    array(),
    null, 
    false
  );
```

or in 1.3

```
echo $html->link(
    $html->image('img.png'),
    'img.png',
    array(),
    array( 'escape' => false ),     
  );
```